# Other transition styles using segue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I've started programming for iOS only for a few weeks, so I don't know how it was done before, but I'd like to use other transition styles for my segues. Like the one where the screen flips, giving you the impression that the destination view controller was on the back of the first one. I suppose I have to subclass UIStoryboardSegue, but apart from that, I have no idea where to go from there.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I didn't look far enough. Select the segue you want to customize, and there's a "transition" style option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CATransition within a custom Segue  to achieve any kind of transition. Here is sample code.

```
-(void)perform {

__block UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
__block UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];                    

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = .25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom



[sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                            forKey:kCATransition];

[sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];    


}
```

You visit this link for more details http://blog.jambura.com/2012/07/05/custom-segue-animation-left-to-right-using-catransition/